# ReactJS change the background color of the selected Navlink in a react bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

So I have a react-bootstrap navbar. I need to change the background color of the selected nav link. My Css is only coloring around the nav link title and not the whole space occupied by this navlink

my navbar:

[mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKepQ.png)

How it should be:

[required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhjdp.png)

My nav bar code:

```
const NavBar = () => {

    let tabs = [
        { name: "Warehouses" },
        { name: "Dispatched to Process" },
        { name: "Sales" },
        { name: "User Manager" },
        { name: "Time Tracking" }
    ];  
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar fixed="top" bg="primary" variant="dark">
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                    {
                        Object.keys(tabs).map(id => {
                            return <NavLink className="my-navbar" to={"/" + tabs[id].name}> {tabs[id].name} </NavLink>
                        })
                    }
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        </>
    );
}

export default NavBar;
```

and finally my nav.css

```
.my-navbar{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 15px  15px 15px  15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.me-auto{
    height: 100%;
}
.my-navbar:visited {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.active {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #61fb69;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The navbar in react-bootstrap already has its own top/bottom padding, so you will have to remove it and give it a height to compensate for the removed padding.
[image]

Next you will have to give all the parent elements of the navitems a height of 100% so that they occupy the full height

```
height: 100%;
align-items: center;
```

You can see here, by default it does not occupy the full height
[image]

Add this css for the .active class

```
height: 100%;
align-items: center;
font-weight: 800;
display: flex;
background-color: #61fb69;
```

This is what I was able to achieve.

[image]

Comment: I applied all the changes you suggested but still got the same result, I will update my css for you to see. thank you so much for helping

Comment: I tested the css on this version of react bootstrap 
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/ 
Maybe the css might be a bit different for your version but the basic idea remains same

Comment: "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the padding for the `my-navbar:hover` to say `padding: 20px 10px`. Keep adjusting the first value until the height for `NavLink<NavLink />` fits that of the `<Nav>'Nav'`.